# creating an XSLT file

Tags: xslt

i have two xml files:

```
<m2> 
 <header> 
  <to>ggg</to> 
  <from>aaa</from> 
  <id>11</id> 
  <name>gd</name> 
  <mtype>me</mtype> 
 </header> 
 <body>some text</body> 
</m2>
```

2.

```
<m2> 
   <header> 
      <desc> 
         <to>ggg</to> 
         <from>aaa</from> 
      </desc> 
      <id>11</id> 
      <name>gd</name> 
      <mtype>nothing</mtype> 
   </header> 
   <body>some text</body> 
</m2>
```

what is the xslt file that convert from the first xml to the second xml?
the xslt need to transform the value of the mtype from "me" to "some text"
and insert the "to" and "from" elements into the "desc" element.

Comment: Downvote for the screenshot instead of actual code samples.

Comment: not fair! i didn't know how to do that!

Comment: Now you know. Upvoted ;)

Comment: @Flack: I explained to @aharon how to format code and he seems to be in the process of doing this correctly. Please, consider cancelling your downvote when @aharon is finished :)

Comment: +1 for learning how to enter code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="to">
  <desc>
   <xsl:copy-of select=".|../from"/>
  </desc>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="mtype/text()">nothing</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="from"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied o the provided XML document, restored from the picture** ( Never do this again!):

```
<m2>
 <header>
  <to>ggg</to>
  <from>aaa</from>
  <id>11</id>
  <name>gd</name>
  <mtype>me</mtype>
 </header>
 <body>some text</body>
</m2>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<m2>
   <header>
      <desc>
         <to>ggg</to>
         <from>aaa</from>
      </desc>
      <id>11</id>
      <name>gd</name>
      <mtype>nothing</mtype>
   </header>
   <body>some text</body>
</m2>
```

**Explanation**: Simple application of the identity rule design pattern. Using and overriding the identity template is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.

**See examples and explanations at: http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html**

Comment: tanks! i know a bit of the xslt ruls, but i don't know those ruls. can you please explain the rules match="node()|@*",select="node()|@*",select=".|../from" and  match="from" (that i didn't understood whay we need this rule).

Comment: @aharon: Just edited my answer to provide a link for the identity rule examples/explanation. Can you, please, edit your question and put the XML docs as normal code? Noone will work with a picture, because they cannot copy and paste it as text.

Comment: i tried to enter this as a regular text, but it didn't work. i saw only the word without "<" how can i enter the code?

Comment: @aharon: You just enter your code, then select it and then finally pres the `{}` button.

Comment: @aharon: I see that someone downvoted you -- it wasn't me. Part of the reason may be because of the pictures.

Comment: can you explain from the part "xsl:template match="to""? i read the link, but i didn't understood this part.

Comment: ok. got it! finding the "to" node, inserting "desc" and then searching for the "to" (".") and the "from" ("../from"- up to the header and select the "from" child. inserting "/desc" and eventually repacing "from" node with "".

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of tutorials for this; just do a web search on "XSLT Tutorial". Here's one of the sites:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: This is not a real answer. It could be a comment but nothing more. Please, do consider to delete it.

Comment: @Alejandro : The original question before editing did not have any code and seemed like a general question on XML translation, which is why I posted the answer I did.